# Application Unable connect Remote Server. FIREWALL Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, port, netstat, soap

Developing a C# Application that uses an WDSL/SOAP service and connects to a server via port 443

I know it is a Firewall Windows 2008 Server issue. Because when I disable it, it works perfectly. Trying to create a rule allowing inbound connections to the port 443, it blocks as well.

Netstat tool just shows that 443 port is attempted to be opened.

Is there any solution to know which port is blocking the access to the remote server in order to open it?

Comment: You're creating the inbound firewall rule on the remote web server or your client server?

Comment: If your application connects to the server on port 443 then you need to configure the firewall on the server to allow inbound connections to port 443.

Comment: @joeqwerty: As I commented, Opening port number 443 (inbound), firewall blocks as well the connection.

Comment: @squillman: On the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule on Windows Firewall called "World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)", and I was allowing just it. It belongs to a program "system" thats why external connections were blocked.

Creating a new rule specifying "All Programs that meet the specified conditions" and the port 443, it worked!